# Laravel 5.2.14 with Duxet/RethinkDB Seeding Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've setup a per project install of Homestead for this project so I don't add RethinkDB to all my Laravel applications.  I've been able very easily setup RethinkDB in Homestead, and migrate the database tables, but I can't seem to seed them.  Running `php artisan db:seed` throws this error in the terminal:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null
```

And this error in laravel.log:

```
[2016-02-11 02:15:39] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:390
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(644): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(duxet\Rethinkdb\Connection), 'insert into "us...', Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(611): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into "us...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(391): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('insert into "us...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(347): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('insert into "us...', Array)
#4 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert('insert into "us...', Array)
#5 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1889): Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), 'insert into "us...', Array, 'id')
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#7 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1244): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1683): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#9 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1652): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#10 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1543): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#11 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php(86): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#12 /home/vagrant/app/database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php(35): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder->create()
#13 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(39): UserTableSeeder->run()
#14 /home/vagrant/app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php(27): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->call('UserTableSeeder')
#15 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(63): DatabaseSeeder->run()
#16 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2347): Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\{closure}()
#17 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(64): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguarded(Object(Closure))
#18 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->fire()
#19 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#21 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#22 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#23 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(185): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#24 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(90): Illuminate\Console\Command->call('db:seed', Array)
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire()
#26 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#28 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(791): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(186): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#32 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /home/vagrant/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /home/vagrant/app/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

My Seed for Users is pretty typical:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Developer accounts
        factory(App\User::class, 'admin', 1)->create([
            'username' => 'test',
            'email' => 'test@domain.com'
        ]);

        factory(App\User::class, 1)->create();
    }
}
```

With a simple model factory:

```
<?php

/**
 * Define a general user factory for seeding the database.
 */
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'username' => $faker->name,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

/**
 * Define an administrator factory for seeding the database.
 */
$factory->defineAs(App\User::class, 'admin', function (Faker\Generator $faker) use ($factory) {

    // Reuse general user factory attributes
    $user = $factory->raw(App\User::class);

    return array_merge($user, [
        'role' => 'admin'
    ]);
});
```

**Update**

It appears it might be an issue between RethinkDB and Laravel, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.  This is the method that the issue occurs in, where I logged out to Laravel.log using monolog, and included the output below the log statements.  It appears the method getPdo() is null.

public function statement($query, $bindings = [])
{
    return $this->run($query, $bindings, function ($me, $query, $bindings) {
        if ($me->pretending()) {
            return true;
        }

```
    Log::info($query);
    // insert into "users" ("username", "password", "email", "remember_token", "role", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

    $bindings = $me->prepareBindings($bindings);

    Log::info($bindings);
    // array (
    //   0 => 'test',
    //   1 => '$2y$10$8icEztzBbFL/556imvn8D.905i67RrCuUwf6csaN2r75W0s0ifg/a',
    //   2 => 'test@domain.com',
    //   3 => 'WUA1vvpyvQ',
    //   4 => 'admin',
    //   5 => '2016-02-11 03:33:29',
    //   6 => '2016-02-11 03:33:29',
    // )

    Log::info($me->getPdo());
    // null

    return $me->getPdo()->prepare($query)->execute($bindings);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this failed due to the User model being the only model that wasn't generate through artisan using make:rethink-model, and it pulls in Authenticatable, which uses the Illuminate Model class.  To fix this it has to be updated manually by removing `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;` and then applying the traits it contains directly to the User model, but then inherits from `use \duxet\Rethinkdb\Eloquent\Model;` so your final User class at the bare minimum will now look like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use \duxet\Rethinkdb\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;


class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```